# Build Fail after removing a file from target membership

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild

I have two deprecated Objective-C files in my project so I just unchecked the target membership of the files. And I am failing on the build everything single time with no useful error message.
It's failing, and only thing showing is

> "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code"

Nothing else. Doesn't even say what part of the project is causing the fail.

The project should run fine without the deprecated files because I commented out all the imports and non of my code is using methods from this file.

Now the odd thing is, even if I check the target membership to what it was, it's still failing, with the same error.

Why is it failing?? And why there is no useful error message??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending three hours of my time finally figured it out. 
Go to build settings and add

swift_enable_batch_mode

Set it to No, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean build. If it doesn't work, delete derived data and try.